# Magento date format issue in Arabic store on customer account page

Tags: store-view, language, date

On customer account page /customer/account/

in English store view date is coming in correct format like 7/11/2013

but when i switch to arabic store view its displaying in wrong format like 72013/11/

It is calling this function:

```
$this->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate())
```

Comment: interesting, it happens also on my machine, but it appears the full and long versions work :(

Comment: hey ... check the answer , i have fixed it... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching a lot i found a solution...

In this file

lib\Zend\Locale\Data\ar.xml

there is tag

```
<dateFormats>
 ....
<dateFormatLength type="short">
   <dateFormat>
       <pattern>d‏/M‏/yyyy</pattern>
   </dateFormat>
</dateFormatLength>
```

It had some spaces in pattern tag so i removed those spaces.. and bingo!! it worked!!

Comment: Nice solution, but still doesn't work for me for some reason. Have to go with the plain php solution - `date("m/j/Y", strtotime($_quote->getCreatedAt()));`